# Dynamic computed property in html

Tags: vuejs2

I'm using php for creating set of computed properties in my app based on ID property of each object in my main array of data stored in property deals. So i have now computed properties like list_10_deals_cnt, list_20_deals_cnt, list_30_deals_cnt etc. Now, how can I create these dynamic created properties in span with class dials__cnt while looping my array of data? {{`'list_'+el.id+'_deals_cnt'`}} is not working as i wish, its display just a string like list_10_deals_cnt instead to display a computed value.
P.S. sorry about my english.

```
  <div class="dials" id="app">

    <div class="dials__column" v-for="(el, index) in deals">
        <div class="dials__header">
            <div>{{el.title}}</div>
            <div>сделок: <span class="dials__cnt">{{`'list_'+el.id+'_deals_cnt'`}}</span>, <span></span> руб</div>
        </div>

      <draggable drag-class="draggable-ghost__class" class="dials__block" :list="el.items" group="deal" @change="log(el.id, $event)">
        <div
          class="dials__card"
          v-for="(el, index) in el.items"
          :key="el.title"
        >
          <div class="card__header">
            <div class="card__title">{{ el.customer_name }}, {{ el.customer_company_name }}</div>
            <div class="card__date">{{ el.created_at }}</div>
          </div>

          <div class="card__body">
            <a :href="'/deal/detail/'+el.id" class="card__link">{{ el.title }}</a>
          </div>

          <div class="card__footer">
            <span class="card__price">{{ el.price }} руб </span>
            <span v-for="(tag, index) in el.tags" class="card__tag">{{ tag }}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </draggable>
    </div>
        
  </div>

    <script>

        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
            deals: <?php echo json_encode($deals, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); ?>
          },
          computed: {
            <?php
            foreach ($deals as $k=>$v) {
                echo 'list_'.$v->id.'_deals_cnt: function() {return this.deals['.$k.'].items.length},';
            }
                ?>
          },
          methods: {
            log: function(id, evt) {
                if (evt.hasOwnProperty('added')) {
                    let dealID = evt.added.element.id;
                    console.log('сделка ID '+dealID+' перемещена в статус '+id+'. Отправляем аякс запрос на обновление статуса в бд');
                    // ajax for update
                }
            }
          }
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Hi

### Problem 1

you will not be able to get the value of computed property by using this

```
{{`'list_'+el.id+'_deals_cnt'`}}
```

for the same reason as `console.log('vari' + 'able')` doesn't print out value of `variable` to the console.
( Vue evaluates whatever is in between `{{ }}` as an expression ).

### Solution

I suppose, you can either use the `deals` property directly in html as shown below without using a computed property

```
<div class="dials__column" v-for="(el, index) in deals">
<div class="dials__header">
   <div>{{el.title}}</div>
   <div>сделок: <span class="dials__cnt">{{ el.items.length }}</span>, <span></span> руб</div>
</div>
----------- rest of the code
```

or you can create a computed property based on `deals` data property and use that to loop in html using `v-for`.

### Problem 2

I don't think below code is valid php string. although it becomes irrelevant if you use first solution above.

```
<?php
   foreach ($deals as $k=>$v) {
      echo 'list_'.$v->id.'_deals_cnt: function() {return this.deals['.$k.'].items.length},';
   }
?>
```

the `'` inside `['.$k.']` should be escaped.

### Solution

```
echo 'list_'.$v->id.'_deals_cnt: function() {return this.deals[\'.$k.\'].items.length},';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I solved this problem
{{generate_computed_property(el.id)}} in my span
and then
                        methods: {
      generate_computed_property: function(id) {
       let str = 'list_'+id+'_deals_cnt';
       return this[str];
      },

Also your {{ el.items.length }} works fine. I'll use it.

Comment: But in second span i need show total price and its changes all time when some deal dragged in other columns. So my solution for that is to use same function in methods section and create list_'.$v->id.'_total_price: function() { in computed section to show dynamic total price.